# COUNT UPDATE between 2 tables

Tags: php, html, mysql

mysql: I've got 2 tables. How do I get the COUNT of **Grade A**'s from table-A for each student and UPDATE the "A Grades Achieved" column in table-B?

[image]

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
$studentName = $line["Student"];

mysql_query("UPDATE table-B SET A Grades Achieved = 
    (SELECT COUNT(A) FROM Table-A 
    WHERE Grade = 'A' && Student ='$studentName') 
    WHERE Student ='$studentName' LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: Don't use spaces in your column names or `-` in your table names.

Comment: Thanks Mike. This was for illustrative purpose only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your query:

```
UPDATE table-B
    SET A Grades Achieved = (SELECT COUNT(A) FROM Table-A WHERE Grade = 'A' && Student ='$studentName')
    WHERE Student ='$studentName'
    LIMIT 1;
```

Apart from the normal comments about SQL injection (your code is prone to it) and "mysql_" being deprecated, your query has some problems.  The major problem is that the names of tables and columns have characters in them that need to be escaped (namely, spaces and hyphens).  Try this:

```
UPDATE `table-B`
    SET `A Grades Achieved` = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Table-A` WHERE Grade = 'A' AND Student = '$studentName')
    WHERE Student = '$studentName'
    LIMIT 1;
```

When designing your database, it is best to have simple names for things, so escaping the names is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your table names and column names, because you used `-` and space characters (which is a bad idea, by the way). You need this:

```
while($line = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $studentName = $line["Student"];

    mysql_query("UPDATE `table-B` SET `A Grades Achieved` = 
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `Table-A` 
        WHERE Grade = 'A' && Student ='$studentName') 
        WHERE Student ='$studentName' LIMIT 1");
```

Also, you really should use prepared statements; this is a major SQL injection risk. See ["Little Bobby Tables."](http://xkcd.com/327/)

Finally, as others have pointed out, mysql_* is deprecated, and you should be using MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

This can actually be done only in SQL:

```
UPDATE students AS s SET s.a_grades_achieved = 
    (SELECT COUNT(student) FROM tests AS t
    WHERE t.student = s.name AND t.grade = 'A');
```

I took the liberty of renaming some fields, so you'll have to modify it for your application. You can see it work in [this fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/588a7/1).